# Characters in text file not recognized

Tags: fonts, character, ascii

I'm nearing the end of a car club project and one of the two remaining problems is a text file I imported, split, parsed, and displayed in a table. Most of the punctuation is not recognized, things like quotes, apostrophes, and dashes, regular stuff like that. Best I can tell this is not a unicode issue. Maybe a font issue? I tried different fonts. I also ran the file through Notepad which usually does a good job stripping out formatting codes.

Here's a screen shot - http://www.kstreetstudio.com/OMC/images/IndexPage.jpg

Here's the code I use to load the file.

```
function FileRead(U) 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        X=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        X=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  X.open('GET', U, false );
  X.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  X.send();
    return X.responseText;
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a font issue, and possibly it's just the wrong type of apostrophe character causing all your problems. Microsoft Wordpad will sometimes automatically select a font to successfully render characters that are otherwise being rendered with the [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/fontsupport.htm) as shown in your screen shot, so just paste your text into WordPad, and if it renders correctly see which font it chose (as shown in a drop list on a toolbar).

Comment: Thanks. I just worked this out last night.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was certain characters not displaying correctly, in particular long dashes and left and right quotes and apostrophes. I was able to find/replace them and the problem went away.